# Getting Duplicate records when running C# WCF service hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created wcf service which downloads excel sheet from remote share point location and converts it into CSV file. 
Issue :
When i am running same wcf service on IIS, it gives me duplicate records in csv file and records doesn't match with actual excel.But when i am running the same wcf service locally it gives me same number of records as in the excel sheet.
is there any issue with IIS hosted wcf??

Comment: Did you try some logging? Create a logging strategy to debug your WCF application, so that you could see what is really doing on your IIS server that differs from your local instance.

Comment: We may have to see some code or configuration details in order to help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause but enabling 32 bit Application support under Application pools advanced settings, helps me resolve the issue.

[image]